# xtightvnxc on pi4 running as root buster xtightvncviewer has no menu bar - can't admin headless pi4 (pi3,2,1 OK) with gui tools

Tags: vnc, headless, root

When xtightvncserver is run as root on Pi4 running buster, vncviewer run from another host (ubuntu 20.04, in this case) there is no menu bar.

When I run xtightvncserver as root on a pi3 (2 or 1) running buster, vncviewer run from another host (ubuntu 20.04, in this case) there is a "normal" menu bar with the menu, browser, terminal, etc.

As such, it seems impossible to administer a headless Pi4 with the gui tools, like system config-printer, using vnc or ssh -X as root (does not set the DISPLAY variable).

Is there some way to get the xtightvncviewer menu bar up when xtightvncserver is run as root or is there a better option to use the gui administration tools on a headless pi4?

BTW "real-vnc" is not an option here because of issues setting it up on other distros like Ubuntu.

Comment: This Question lacks any meaningful data and is unanswerable. You **CAN** use `RealVNC` on the Pi and access with other viewer clients - you need to use different authentication.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.  My issue with RealVNC is that in order to use RealVNC, one must create an personal account at the RealVNC website and there is the potential that internal network security and individual privacy could be compromised if "meaningful data" is sent to the vendor each time RealVNC is used ... a potential "big brother is watching" scenario that simply does not exist with any other vnc package.  I should have included this in the original question.

Comment: Rubbish! I run RealVNC on all my Pi and have never created an account.